# How to suspend and resume a Process and Thread in C++

Tags: c++, c

i wan't to suspend and resume main function is there any way except sleep method. Please Help

Comment: too vague, What are you really trying to do? a sleep? or wait for a condition on another thread ?
see pthread in this case https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Detention would be a more appropriate punishment.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419068/stdmutexlock-blocking-cpu-usage/22419120#comment34090624_22419120

Comment: i wan't to avoid spin lock...just when one event has done then i wan't to continue my main() method execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have other threads running apart from main, you can use use a `sem_wait` (semaphore initialized to 0) in `main()` and then from your thread you can call `sem_post` whenever you want `main()` to run.

[Read](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/23-Concurrency-Examples.pdf) about semaphore and usage:

Comment: plz tell me if i do sem_wait (2 times) then after doing sem_post one time does it invoke the one thread if semaphore is initialized to 0

Comment: The value of `semaphore` has to be `>=1` for `sem_wait` to proceed. If you start with initial value `0`, then `sem_wait` will block untill `sem_post` increments it by `1` to `1`. For every `sem_wait`, there has to be a corresponding `sem_post` which unblocks the blocked thread. Hope this helps you!

Comment: but after 2 sem_wait and 1 sem_post whether the first thread that is blocked will continue or need one more sem_post which will then continue running the two threads at same time (init with 0)

Comment: and if initialized with 0 then sem_wait will block and makes value equal -1 then after sem_post its value will bcm 0 and thread will be unblocked so it does not need value >=1

Comment: Whether it remains `0` or goes `negative`, is implementation dependent, either way the concept is the same. I'll talk about the version where it remains at zero. For `sem_wait` to proceed, the value of `semaphore` has to be `non-zero`. If it's `zero`, then it waits, no decrement operation is performed. If the value is `0` and two threads perform `sem_wait` then  value remains at zero, not decremented. WHenever the 1st `sem_post` occurs, value is incremented by 1, the thread that had been waiting for longer time proceeeds, makes sem value back to `0`. Check out the link I have added in the ans.